# Difference between $MyInvocation and $PSScriptRoot

Tags: powershell, difference

*Edited to better explain overall question:*

In PowerShell, what is the difference between using `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` and `$PSScriptRoot` for acquiring the running script's current root directory, if any?

My research only indicates that the two are basically interchangeable and that one wasn't introduced until PowerShell v3. I have also been told that `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`, although not pretty/elegant, has some functionality to it that isn't fully supported by `$PSScriptRoot`.

So the overall question is:

Are there any Pros and/or Cons between these two PowerShell commands? Are there instances in which you'd rather use one over the other?

**@Mathias R. Jessen:** I can understand how you are quick to judge this question; however, it is NOT a duplicate and is especially NOT a duplicate of the question you have pointed this to, which asks "how do I get the root directory". My question isn't HOW do I get the root directory, it is WHAT is the difference in functionality between these two commands. And seeing as you nor anyone else has come back to review my revisions, I am forced to re-ask this question.

For example:

If I am running this script remotely or I am utilizing Jenkins to invoke the base script and I chose to utilize `$PSScriptRoot` over `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`, would there be a problem or would I essentially have the same exact functionality?

If I have no way to determine whether the server I chose to run the script on has PSv3, but my script was written using PSv3, would using `$PSScriptRoot` cause problems?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$PSScriptRoot` was added in PSv3 as an easy way to find the current script's location without having to parse `$MyInvocation`.  They're both automatic variables that get assigned at runtime.  Use `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables` at the commandline.

Comment: `$PSScriptRoot` isn't available in Powershell version 1 and 2. So `MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` had to be used.

Comment: One advantage of `$MyInvocation` is the scope specifier.  I'm unsure if `$PSScriptRoot` offers the same level of manipulation.  For example, `$MyInvocation` also refers to the current function it gets invoked in, so you can use `$script:MyInvocation` to get script-level information.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible: Thank you, that is one of the examples/answers I was looking for

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Scope modifiers work with either variable.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Functionally, changing the scope of `$PSScriptRoot` won't make a difference, though, unless, perhaps, working with a module.